# Python pandas groupby compare lists

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have 2 csv files with memberlists that I want to compare.
As result I would like to have 1 list with all members and an indication in which list they appear and also I would like to calculate the dropout.
I would like to do this with pandas.

First file:

```
ID,LastName,FirstName,BirthDate
1,A,a,01/01/1901
2,B,b,01/01/1902
3,C,c,01/01/1903
4,D,d,01/01/1904
```

Second file:

```
ID,LastName,FirstName,BirthDate
1,A,a,01/01/1901
4,D,d,01/01/1904
5,E,e,01/01/1905
6,F,f,01/01/1906
```

Result:

```
ID,LastName,FirstName,BirthDate,Old,New
1,A,a,01/01/1901,Yes,Yes
2,B,b,01/01/1902,Yes,No
3,C,c,01/01/1903,Yes,No
4,D,d,01/01/1904,Yes,Yes
5,E,e,01/01/1905,No,Yes
6,F,f,01/01/1906,No,Yes
```

Calculate DropOut:
Members not in second file / total members in both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill "Old" column in `df1` and "New" column in `df2`:

```
df1["Old"]="Yes"
df2["New"]="Yes"
```

then:

```
pd.merge(
    df1.reset_index(),
    df2.reset_index(),
    how="outer"
).fillna("No").set_index("ID")
```

output:

```
ID  LastName    FirstName   BirthDate   Old New
1   A   a   01/01/1901  Yes Yes
2   B   b   01/01/1902  Yes No
3   C   c   01/01/1903  Yes No
4   D   d   01/01/1904  Yes Yes
5   E   e   01/01/1905  No  Yes
6   F   f   01/01/1906  No  Yes
```

to read csv files just use `pd.read_csv("csv_path.csv")`, while to export you can use the `to_csv` method of `pd.DataFrame` object (for example cou can do `pd.merge(...).to_csv("output_csv_path.csv")`).

consult the pandas documentation for other details.